# i can't find my saved android sdk in preference in eclipse

Tags: android

I'm at chapter 2 of android application development for dummies:prepping your development headquarters, and in a step it tells me to set sdk location but it can't find it but i did the step to put it in my environmental variable. How do i find it.

Answer (score 1):

If some books asked you to setup Eclipse for Android Development, then it your turn to drop that book and try another.
Use Android Studio for Android Application Development.